# Clarify data process for auth0 cookies

Tags: cookies

I'm posting a question here but may be even advice is already good.

To be complied with the GDPR, we are now requested by legal department to clarify the data processing for the cookies we use. For each cookie, we need to clarify:

- What data it process
- Does that data processing involve a server (like sent to the server) or just proceeded locally
- Combine with other information to decide if the cookie is processing personal data or not.

Among the cookies we are having on our website, there are 3rd party cookies set by auth0 custom domain, they are:
[image]

Now it's really hard for us to fulfill the request because from what we know and from the document we found on auth0 website, the information we're looking for is not available.

Please help to give advice on how should we find the information we're requested.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find some information here: https://auth0.com/docs/manage-users/cookies/authentication-api-cookies. Also I'd advice you to contact Auth0 directly as they are your "processor" and obliged (under the GDPR article 28) to provide you with the information you need. Unless you can read javascript, you need to ask Auth0 for the purpose(s) of each cookie.

The answer for your 2nd question depends on your implementation. If those are 3rd party cookies (set by Auth0), then they always involve a 3rd party server. This means that personal data (IP addresses) are always processed when those cookies are used.

You will get the answer for your 3rd question once you get information on the purposes of each cookie (why they are being set).

Also your legal team would probably want to know the location of those servers (where end users fetch those cookies). As IP-addresses and other traffic data are being processed, it might involve transfers to 3rd countries (and this is where the GDPR gets really complicated).